# Find out how drag ended when implementing UICollectionViewDragDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop, uikit

I'm implementing drag and drop. Most of the drag sources and destinations in the app are custom views, so I just use `UIDragInteraction` and `UIDropInteraction`. However, one drag source is a collection view, so I use `UICollectionView`'s own dragging support via `UICollectionViewDragDelegate`.

The issue is that when the drag is done, I need to know if it finished successfully or was cancelled/aborted. `UIDragInteractionDelegate` has a `dragInteraction(_:, session:, didEndWith:)` method where the last argument is a UIDropOperation (e.g. .copy , .cancel, etc.), and in most source, I can use this to do the appropriate thing depending on whether the drop was successful.

By contrast, `UICollectionViewDragDelegate`'s corresponding `collectionView(_:, dragSessionDidEnd:)` doesn't include the drop operation. Am I missing something or is there no way to know how the drag ended if you're using `UICollectionViewDragDelegate` instead of implementing `UIDragInteractionDelegate` directly? I'd really rather not duplicate the implementation work `UICollectionView` already has to make dragging easy just for this one little thing.